# Did I set this relational database up correctly (python, sqlite3)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to make a relational database that connects 3 different tables. The main program database contains the vendors, that links to invoices from each vendor, then the invoices links to items purchased in that invoice.

```
tempcur.execute("""CREATE TABLE program (
                     vendorid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                     vendor TEXT, 
                     phone TEXT, 
                     store INTEGER)""")

tempcur.execute("""CREATE TABLE dairystore (
                     invoice INTEGER REFERENCES program(vendorid), 
                     date VARCHAR)""")

tempcur.execute("""CREATE TABLE invoices(
                     item INTEGER REFERENCES dairystore(invoice), 
                     shipped VARCHAR, 
                     description TEXT, 
                     weight INTEGER, 
                     price INTEGER, 
                     amount INTEGER)""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have a mistake in `dairystore` table. It should be the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dairystore (
  invoice INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
  vendor INTEGER REFERENCES program(vendorid), 
  date VARCHAR
)
```

You're trying to reference to `dairystore.invoice` from `invoices` table, so `dairystore.invoice` must be the id of record. In your code `dairystore.invoice` can't be the id of record because it is reference to `program.vendorid` and its values will be equal to ids of records in `program` table.

Comment: And can you give me a quick answer as to why I need to add the 'vendor INTEGER REFERENCES program(vendorid)' line for knowledge purposes? Is it not possible to link to the invoice number??

Comment: Added some explanation. I'm not sure it's clear. No, your invoices table is correct.

Comment: Thanks, just one issue, Then I believe I should be good: The dairystore.invoice column isn't suppose to be auto-incremented. It is a number that will be manually inserted. Which is why I didn't use it as a primary key...So how does that change the equation?

Comment: It can be not auto increment, but it has to be primary key. So values inserted by user must be unique.